# Can mechanical agitation increase the reaction rate?

Tags: acid-base

The specific example I saw recently was cleansing of concrete (portland cement) film from brick using a diluted muriatic acid. It appeared that the more scrubbing was used, the quicker the cleaning process would go. That seems to match up with everyday experience.

However what is not clear is how that mechanical agitation was specifically improving the reaction rate.

More generally, are there a 'class' of reactions or reagents where mechanical agitation will alter the reaction rate? And is that affecting the actual reaction or more just the process efficiency?

Answer (score 4):

If the reaction is heterogeneous (multiple phases involved), mechanical agitation helps. If the reaction is homogeneous (all reactants and products in the same phase), mechanical agitation usually does not help. An exception is when the process is auto-catalytic (i.e. starts in one corner and then propagates).

In the example mentioned, agitation will help to transport concrete away from the brick surface and to bring fresh acid to the surface. Scrubbing also helps if there is no chemical reaction and the removal is mechanical in nature.

Comment: In the concrete example I'm pretty sure that's an actual reaction - it produces a gas aside from the fact that scrubbing alone would not be able to clean portland cement from brick :)  Thanks for answering generally not only to my example.

Comment: Butt it is the same. You need fresh acid to get in contact to the wall . The reaction as its rate as a virtual system. The point is that mechanical agitation ensures the conditions to be renewed homogeneously.

Answer (score 3):

At the molecular scale, a reaction will not become faster by stirring or agitation.  At larger, macroscopic scale you may however increase the overall rate because agitation mixes the reactants with each other and hence increases the propability over time that they are exposed to each other.  Especially in the case of heterogenous reactions like the one described by you, you equally have to consider transport of matter *across matter* by diffusion.  See [Diffusion laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fick's_laws_of_diffusion), for a starter.  Even less quick are transport rates *passing* phase boundaries like crystallite grains to liquid.

This is why brushing the surfaces both brought new reactants into contact, and removed products formed which otherwise could have hampered the reaction to progress.